# Borel-measurable function

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measurable-functions

The original question is:
 Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F})$ a measurable space with $\mathcal{F}=({\emptyset , \Omega})$. Show that a function $f:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$ is borel-measurable, if and only if $f$ is constant.
I know that the inverse image of any real interval is $\emptyset$ or $\Omega$, thence if is $\emptyset$ the image of all element of $\Omega$ is in the complement of the interval, and if it is $\Omega$ all element of $\Omega$ have image in the interval, but I don't know how to continue this proof.

Can you help me?.

Comment: Take the inverse image of a singleton contained in the image of $f$.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose there exist $x$ and $y$ such that $f(x)\neq f(y)$.
Then $A\equiv f^{-1}(f(x))$ contains $x$ but does not contain $y$.
In other words, $A$ is neither the empty set or the whole space $\Omega$.